# how to Register for listener in Accelerometer using C

Tags: c, embedded, accelerometer

I am working on an STM32f2xx processor eval board, with LIS3lv02dh accelerometer chipset.

I have been able able to program the accelerometer to wakeup the processor on interrupt based on the Threshold level change in accelerometer, but how do I register for events during wakeup.

How do I register an accelerometer sensor handler so that when an interrupt occurs, the application code is notified.

Comment: Please write standard English, including spaces and capitals.

Comment: Two questions: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/); And what platform/hardware?

Comment: hi, i was working on STM32f2xx processor eval board, with LIS3lv02dh accelerometer chipset....i could able program the accelerometer to wakeup the processor on interrupt based on the Threshold level change in acccelerometer. but how do i register for events during wakeup. when i was trying to browse in google, i found most of the search links to be in Android & java based solutions, since i m not aware of java and android, i couldnt able to find any solutions to do with it.

Comment: The information in your comment should be added to the question!  If you do that it might avoid being closed for being unanswerable!

Comment: Improve the question with the precise part and/or evaluation board you are using (preferably with links)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read and understand the STM32f2xx User Reference Manual.  You have no OS (I guess) and generic Google searches will not help you; the problem is very specific to the parts you are using.

The STM32F2xxx Standard Peripheral Library (downloadable from ST's site) contains numerous examples for all peripherals including I believe using wake-up sources.

If the accelerometer is included on the evaluation board, I would imagine that it includes example code or a support library that may help.